# Number of steps to rotate for convergence in a circle

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, rotations

I am trying to come up with a formula to calculate how many rotations of discrete steps I need to converge on the exact same point on a circle. For instance I start at $0$ degrees and rotate $45$ degrees $8$ times to converge back to the $0$ degree marker. Now I am trying to find a formula that will work for any step size $\lt360$ degrees. The closest I can come up with is either one of:

$$1)\qquad (XY) \bmod 360 = 0$$

or

$$2)\qquad \frac{XY}{360} = Z$$

I think it will take a combination of these, the first one to know when I've found a suitable multiple of $360^\circ$ and the second to figure out exactly how many rotations it took. It's been a long time since I have done any trig or formal algebra so a quick refresher or even a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Edit: A bit more info is needed I think. I am trying to figure out if and when a musical scale will become a closed system. A scale is normally generated by continuously stacking an interval until it converges on an octave. An example is that $$ 2^{(\frac{1}{12})} = 1.059463 $$ using the formula $$ 1200 * \frac{\log 2^{(\frac{1}{12})}}{\log 2} = 700 $$ We see that a tempered perfect fifth is exactly 700 cents. To transfer this into degrees we simply do $$ 700 (\frac{360}{1200}) = 210° $$ I know that 210° will converge after 12 steps which will produce exactly 7 rotations on a circle. The complication comes in when an interval is not expressed in cents as an integer. for instance a natural perfect fifth is the ratio $$ 1200 * \frac{\log 2^{(\frac{3}{2})}}{\log 2} = 701.955 $$ Which turns out to be 210.5865°. So I need to figure out how many steps until convergence and how many rotations it would be in total. The GCD method will work for integers but I was hoping for a way to do it with any real number. The results of this method should always produce integers though, but should work for any real number input. I basicly want to short cut the process of actually stacking the intervals.

Comment: It is (for integer number $x$ of degrees), $\frac{360}{\gcd(x,360)}$. But this may not be helpful.

Comment: An anonymous person did an edit for which the summary was "Applied MathJax".  MathJax had not been used originally.  Where it said (X*Y) Mod 360 = 0 someone left the code exactly like that, with even a capital "M", and put it in math mode.  Using an asterisk for ordinary multiplication in TeX or LaTeX or MathJax is horribly vulgar, and one when one writes a\bmod b it appears as $a\bmod b$, with proper spacing and non-italicized $\bmod$, whereas "a Mod b" looks like this: $a Mod b$.  Yet someone approved the edit instead of improving it.  (I then improved it.)

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to come out even if the number of degrees is irrational.  You can come as close to a multiple of $360^\circ$ as you like, but won't get there.  Your value of $2^{\frac 1{12}}$ is not exact, the number is irrational.  The formula for a perfect fifth you give is not correct, as $\frac {\log 2^{\frac 32}}{\log 2}=\frac 32$ so $1200 \cdot \frac {\log 2^{\frac 32}}{\log 2}=1800$  It is true that a natural perfect fifth is about $702$ cents

If your number is rational, you can come out even.  If it is $\frac ab$ in lowest terms, you need to multiply it by $\frac {ab}{\gcd(a,360)}$ to get the first multiple of $360$.  You will make $\frac {360}{\gcd(a,360)}$ full rotations.